# Как отключить вывод сохранения пароля при срабатывании preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проверяю форму при помощи Jquery.
Если при нажатии submit в форме находятся ошибки, срабатывает preventDefault()
Но в браузерах выскакивает предложение с сохранением логина и пароля.
Как именно в этом случае отменить заблокировать выскакивание сохранения (так как форма не верна и может вообще нет смысла сохранять это)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 атрибут [`autocomplete=off`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) и CSS свойство [`-webkit-text-securit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-security)